# Linking to Custom Post type img src

Tags: wordpress

I have set up some custom post types in WordPress and have used a field for an Image.
I have added to following to functions:

```
if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}
add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 190, 190, true);
```

which has given me the option in advance custom fields to choose this as the image size displayed, however I would like to link this image to the full size version as well. Can anyone help me with this as I am at a loss of what to do from here!

Here is the code for the page:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'chairs',
    );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );?>
<?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'chairs',
    );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );?>
<?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="grid-container productmargin-right">
                <div class="grid-4 product-image">
                    <?php $attachment_id = get_field('image');
                        $size = "homepage-thumb"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
                        // url = $image[0];
                        // width = $image[1];
                        // height = $image[2];
                        ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
                </div>

                <div class="grid-8">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                    <h3><?php the_field('additional_information'); ?></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end of item -->
<?php endwhile; endif?>
```

Comment: Do you want the thumbnail on your site and the full size image if you click the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already getting the URL for the custom image size. Use the same function to get the full image URL and then wrap your image in an anchor tag.

Change this:

```
<?php $attachment_id = get_field('image');
$size = "homepage-thumb"; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
// url = $image[0];
// width = $image[1];
// height = $image[2];
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
```

To:

```
<?php $attachment_id = get_field('image');

// we don't need a size variable. pass size directly as a parameter.
$thumb_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'homepage-thumb' );

// get the full size image.
$full_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' ); ?>

<a href="<?php echo $full_image[0]; ?>">
   <img src="<?php echo $thumb_image[0]; ?>" />
</a>
```

It would also be a good idea to add some validation. Make sure the image has been set before attempting to run `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`.